# How to make the background fog like Verold

Tags: three.js

how to make the background like this demo (http://studio.verold.com/projects/527bb3faa6c4c30200000564)     but don't use the skybox ?

Verold call this is skybox fog but i'm not see any skybox fog on google.

Thanks.

Comment: well, if you rotate the camera so that it looks to the ground and zoom out, you can see the object disappear in a brown fog, so there is fog overall. But the effect in general is quite interesting and i am not sure how it is done. But could really be a skybox with white on top and brown below and a fog volume added in there for the lower part of the scene?

Comment: There are over 40 three.js examples of using fog. For example, [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html) one.